# What if we use only "else" block for "if...else" statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, syntax

I know that "if" statement can be used without the "else" block in javascript. But what if I need an "else" block only? What syntax should be in this case?

```
    if (req.body[data].length <= maxlength[indx]); // <===== semicolon
    else {
      req.body[data] = 'ERROR: too long';
      status = 404;
    }
```

or

```
    if (req.body[data].length <= maxlength[indx]) {} // <===== empty block
    else {
      req.body[data] = 'ERROR: too long';
      status = 404;
    }
```

ECMA stanadrt says nothing about this case (https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-12.5)

Comment: why not just invert the logic of the `if` test

Comment: But if I invert the logic I'll be say in the code: "status = 404;" several times in a row

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, but it might help clarify if you would add to your question with an example of why inverting the logic of the `if` statement is undesirable.

Comment: And, at least in this case, the inversion makes more sense from a cognitive standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what others have answered:

In your specific case, you can just invert the operant so `<=` would become `>`.

In other cases, you can use `!` to achieve what you are trying to do.

```js
    if (req.body[data].length <= maxlength[indx]); // <===== semicolon
    else {
      req.body[data] = 'ERROR: too long';
      status = 404;
    }
```

should become

```js
    if (req.body[data].length > maxlength[indx]) {
      req.body[data] = 'ERROR: too long';
      status = 404;
    }
```

The idea is to do the opposite of the condition in your original post which achieves the same purpose of having only an `else` statement. This way the code remains easier to read and reason about.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Inverting the logic seems like the most plausible option here. Actually inverting logic is also related to code readability, if you invert the logic and place them at the beginning they are often referred to as Guard Clauses which improves readability a lot. You can check that topic out.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, how can I do ?

```js
if (!address.street && !address.postcode && !address.city && !address.country)
 {    } 
else {result = await geocode(address)}
```